# Cannot deploy project due to missing type

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, scratch-org, cli

I am currently trying to deploy my project, but are getting some errors which I am unsure how I should navigate.

> Error WebCart
> Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix (e.g. __c)

It is perceived as a custom object because of the meta.xml states it to be a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <actionOverrides>
```

how do make it a non-custom object?

Comment: In the metadata, _all_ SObjects fall under the `<CustomObject>` umbrella (including Standard SObjects like `Account`). I think we'll need more information to be able to help you on this one.

Answer (score 0):

> **WebCart** represents an online shopping cart for a store built with B2B Commerce or D2C Commerce, with total amounts for products, shipping and handling, and taxes.

You did not specify in your question, but I'm assuming you are trying to deploy this to a non-production environment, such as a scratch org or a sandbox. **For a sandbox**, you have no option other than have the B2B Commerce licenses available in production first and then trigger a refresh of that sandbox environment to access this kind of object. **For a scratch org**, you can create a new one with the `B2BCommerce` value in the `feature` attribute.

Finally, if you are trying to deploy to any kind of environment, your user *might* need to have access to the Web Cart object, which requires your user to have the B2B Commerce license assigned to it. If you are working with a Salesforce org that already has B2B Commerce enabled, make sure your user has that license assigned to it.

1. [Since Spring '21 you can create scratch orgs with B2B Commerce licenses.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_scratch_org_b2b_commerce.htm&release=230&type=5)